# Forms - Multiple Checkboxes Default Values Not Populating

Tags: forms, sessions

I have a Drupal 7 form using multiple checkboxes. The default value is based on a session variable. However, if I uncheck all of the boxes, I still have a default session variable but it is not populating the correct checkbox in the form. If someone could help point out the bug it would be appreciated:

```
$types = array('option1'=>'This is Option 1',
                   'option2'=>'This is Option 2');

$form['type'] = array(
    '#title' => t('<span class="controltext">Type</span>'),
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
        'control-box',
        'container-inline'),
        'onClick'=>'this.form.submit();'),
    '#options' => $types,
    '#default_value' => (!empty($_SESSION['type'])) ? $_SESSION['type'] : NULL,
);
drupal_set_message('<pre>'.print_r($_SESSION['type'],true).'</pre>');
```

This prints out:

```
Array
(
    [0] => option1
)
```

Comment: What `#options` are available? Where is $types coming from?

Comment: You tell us what's in `$triptypes`, and then you use another variable in `'#options' => $types,`. Also, please use devel module to inspect variables - it will also give you character count. Now we don't know if there are whitespaces in your array.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I made an error in the array name when posting it on this forum.